# Kickstarter GraphQL API with Scrapy Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql, scrapy

I am trying to pull specific data for some projects listed in kickstarter.com.

Kickstarter.com uses GraphQL and I am trying to make a copy of that API, it worked with Python requests library but when I used it in scrapy requests it kept returning error 403.

I assume the problem is in content-type but I failed to find the correct one that I should use, noting that it works exactly like this when I use normal requests library.

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/graph"
    payload = json.dumps([
    {
        "operationName": "Campaign",
        "variables": {
        "slug": "leightonconnor/akashic-titan-blue-bolt"
        },
        "query": "query Campaign($slug: String!) {\n  project(slug: $slug) {\n    id\n    isSharingProjectBudget\n    risks\n    story(assetWidth: 680)\n    currency\n    spreadsheet {\n      displayMode\n      public\n      url\n      data {\n        name\n        value\n        phase\n        rowNum\n        __typename\n      }\n      dataLastUpdatedAt\n      __typename\n    }\n    environmentalCommitments {\n      id\n      commitmentCategory\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
    }
    ])
    headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-csrf-token': 'AZsT67Z9s-LHZt6ZJXLSQWJlNdd7biKz2XDfFMkcYMZrNufH1OWoFhNBlXIvxCrxKRzV6l8bG_Z6QlcRoYMe_g',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_ksr_session=fc2U7qXXaRN91foNiE53NyU3s181NZO0Ll57xPkYxZ5iyUNgus35a0HwsPBTfViBY%2ByAKbtpRirAVLxOGKzG%2BYMOmsLRBPujZep%2Fca%2B1%2FXzW3xX56VXkh5w6ItYhIctEFifQQhw3rTmvoljyHw%3D%3D--4pK6xBEgChjqgmte--LH4Q1qSnhU%2FYX9JgTzGuSQ%3D%3D;'
    }
    print('..ok')
    yield scrapy.Request(url, method="POST", headers=headers, body=payload, callback=self.parse_project)
```

Returns:

```
2022-02-23 07:06:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST https://www.kickstarter.com/graph> (referer: None)
2022-02-23 07:06:55 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.kickstarter.com/graph>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Code in Python Requests (works):

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/graph"

payload = json.dumps([
  {
    "operationName": "Campaign",
    "variables": {
      "slug": "leightonconnor/akashic-titan-blue-bolt"
    },
    "query": "query Campaign($slug: String!) {\n  project(slug: $slug) {\n    id\n    isSharingProjectBudget\n    risks\n    story(assetWidth: 680)\n    currency\n    spreadsheet {\n      displayMode\n      public\n      url\n      data {\n        name\n        value\n        phase\n        rowNum\n        __typename\n      }\n      dataLastUpdatedAt\n      __typename\n    }\n    environmentalCommitments {\n      id\n      commitmentCategory\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
  }
])
headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'x-csrf-token': 'AZsT67Z9s-LHZt6ZJXLSQWJlNdd7biKz2XDfFMkcYMZrNufH1OWoFhNBlXIvxCrxKRzV6l8bG_Z6QlcRoYMe_g',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
  'cookie': '_ksr_session=fc2U7qXXaRN91foNiE53NyU3s181NZO0Ll57xPkYxZ5iyUNgus35a0HwsPBTfViBY%2ByAKbtpRirAVLxOGKzG%2BYMOmsLRBPujZep%2Fca%2B1%2FXzW3xX56VXkh5w6ItYhIctEFifQQhw3rTmvoljyHw%3D%3D--4pK6xBEgChjqgmte--LH4Q1qSnhU%2FYX9JgTzGuSQ%3D%3D;'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json()[0]['data']['project']['risks'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it worked for me:

1. Open the page you want to scrape.
2. Look under the network tab in inspection tools.
3. find the GraphQl request that contains the information you want.
4. right click on it and go to copy > copy as curl (bash). (This is assuming that you are using chrome, I think other browsers have it too but I use chrome).
5. Go to [curl2scrapy](https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/) and paste your curl command. it will give you the headers and payload.
6. Before you run it replace all `\n` in the query with `\\n`.

Comment: curl2scrapy is amazing! This will save me much time in the future, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone come here (like me) who is struggeling in general make post request to an graphql api (not specific on kickstarter).
My initial situation was the same, I had a working requests. Request but was not able to convert it to Scrapy.

tldr: Compare your complete requests in my case the header of scrapy request was not sufficient.

In general something like that should work with scrapy (scrapy shell in this case):

```
q = """
    query GetSomething($xId: ID!) { 
          x(id: $xId) {
            title}
            }
    """

j = {'query': q, 'variables': {
                'xId': "12345",
            }}

scrapy_request = Request(url=url, method='POST',
                         body=json.dumps(j),
                         )

fetch(scrapy_request)
```

But keep in mind that requests may modify your request in other way as scrapy do. Especcially If you have custom middleware or something else.
So investigate if your headers contain correct entries of eg.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

or

```
'Accept': '*/*',
```

To compare your requests someone in scrapy discord channel recommended http://httpbin.org/ as tool to have an endpoint which returns status 200.
After that you can compare responses body and headers to find sensitive differences.